# How to look up with foreing keys?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I'm starting with Django and I want to get the movies that have a better rating score and I don't know how to find a way using my model state. Now there are my classes:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    movieId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    anno = models.IntegerField()
    imdbId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    tmdbId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Rating(models.Model):
    rating = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp = models.IntegerField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)+"--"+str(self.rating)
```

Comment: Movies that have a better rating score than *what*? How are movies rated here? The average? What if there are no ratings for a movie?

Comment: Yes, sorry. All the movies has some rating objects, so the best ones are the movies that have a better average rating. And the rating class has the rating integer attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For a given movie `some_movie`, you can obtain the set of *related* `Rating`s, with:

```
some_movie.rating_set.all()
```

If you want to calculate, for *every* movie, the *average* rating, you can `.annotate(..)` your `Movie` queryset, for example with:

```
from django.db.models import Avg

Movie.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Avg('rating__rating')
)
```

In that case, the `Movie`s in *that* queryset will have an attribute `.avg_rating` that contains the average of the ratings (or `None` if there are no ratings).

We can also use this annotation for filtering purposes, for example the following will give us *all* movies with an average rating larger than or equal to `3`:

```
# movies with an average rating larger than or equal to 3

from django.db.models import Avg

Movie.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Avg('rating__rating')
).filter(
    avg_rating___gte=3
)
```

We can also use this to order our movies, for example ordering the `Movie`s from larger average ratings to smaller average ratings:

```
# order movies best to worse (by average rating)

from django.db.models import Avg

Movie.objects.annotate(
    avg_rating=Avg('rating__rating')
).order_by('-avg_rating')
```